# How to reverse connection initiator in IdTCPClient and IdTCPServer having the same functionality?

Tags: delphi, indy, nat

I would like to create Inter Machine Communication using INDY TCP Client and Server components. IdTCPServer has an event called OnExecute which is triggered when client wants something from server. I would like to create the same functionality, when SERVER sends request to the CLIENT which would have the same OnExecute event, just like it was working as server. Is it easily to achieve? I need it because I can connect to the peer only one-way (NAT)

Answer (score 1):

> IdTCPServer has an event called OnExecute which is triggered when client wants something from server.

That is not how the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event works.  It is called in a continuous loop for the lifetime of the connection, regardless of anything that the client or server do with the connection between the time it is connected and the time it is disconnected.

The *typical* usage of the event is to block the calling thread waiting for the client to send a packet, then reply with a packet, and then exit, letting the loop fire the event again so it can wait for the next client packet.

But this is not the *only* way the event can be used.

> I would like to create the same functionality, when SERVER sends request to the CLIENT which would have the same OnExecute event, just like it was working as server. Is it easily to achieve?

`TIdTCPClient` does not implement that kind of logic natively.  It merely provides a connection, but you have to write your own code to tell it when to read and write data over that connection.

For what you are asking, you will need to create your own worker thread, either by writing a `TThread`/`TIdThread`-derived class, or using the `TIdThreadComponent` component.  When the client connects to the server, start the thread.  When the client disconnects, stop the thread.  Then your thread can do whatever you want with the connection, just like with the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event.

Depending on the format of your commands/responses, you *might* be able to use `TIdCmdTCPClient` instead of `TIdTCPClient`.  `TIdCmdTCPClient` runs its own thread internally, and its `CommandHandlers` collection parses inbound requests and generates outgoing responses.  All you would have to do is populate the collection with `TIdCommandHandler` objects that define the parsing criteria for each request, and assign an `OnCommand` event handler to each one to react to each request that the server sends.